# How to add product size attribute dropdown in product listing page?

Tags: product, prestashop-1.6

I want to display a dropdown of various product sizes available on the product listing page (changing product size changes prices) in my Prestashop 1.6 store.

I was able to display the sizes available (not selectable) so far but unable to add a selectable dropdown.

I want the following result - 
[Desired Result](http://postimg.org/image/4ac7qp8wr/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is repeating but i will give you the solution

Go to **Catalog > Attributes and Values**
Create a **new Attribute** (e.g. Size in grams)
Create **new values** for that attribute: 200gm, 500gm
Now go to **Catalog > Products** and choose your product
Choose the **Combination tab**
You can use the **Product combinations generator** and
specify the price to each size
Solution worked for me

Comment: that displays the size in product info but not in product list page.

Comment: I do know a module that does that. But it is a paid module    http://www.presto-changeo.com/en/attribute-modules/59-product-list-attributes.html

Comment: It will require a lot of changes in controllers and template files. This is one solution that i found helpful    https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/279551-how-to-show-product-attribute-option-in-product-list/?p=2032500